# Beginner needs help with texture and lighting

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, lighting

First of all I’m a newbie to 3D software and I decided to use blender since I read somewhere that blender got a new update which improved the UI, plus it was free.
My question is, I was following this tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pi1MxqpmKw) (skip to 10:55) and I noticed that my textures and lighting was totally different from his.

[image]

Any Tips?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome! There are many ways to be "different", but think you should check which render engine is used in this video (either Cycles or Eevee).

Comment: Hey, if you want to see some cool videos made with blender, check out the open movies.